# What is the maximum voltage of high voltage differential SCSI?

Tags: scsi

Is the maximum voltage of high voltage differential SCSI documented somewhere? All I can find in various source like Wikipedia is that it is "greater than 5 volts" ... but how high can it actually be?

I have seen what HVD can do to a single ended SCSI controller ... burns the copper traces right off the circuit board, so there is definitely a lot of power on that bus. But just how much power?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HVD in the SCSI standards was 'according to RS-485', which allows up to -7V and +12V
on the differential wiring, though limits the difference signal to the (0V, 5V)
range.   There is a separate line in SCSI standards for identifying HVD, LVD (low-voltage differential) and single-ended (SE, based on each pair of wires
being one dedicated ground, and one open-collector driven).   Unless the identification is ignored, a HVD or LVD driver will not engage (the drivers
just stay in high-impedance state), so damage is rarely an issue, though
function is.

A typical offering used only +5V and ground, like this one [AHA3944UWD](https://web.archive.org/web/20150922132827/http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/scsi/3940/aha-3944auwd/)  and
would offer ONLY all-HVD device bus function (and power-off if a LVD or SE
device were attached).   The difficulty arises if an HVD driver attempts
to lift the always-grounded second wire of an SE bus device, or applies
high overvoltage to an LVD input.   A typical driver for HVD (SN75176B)
is capable of putting 150 mA into its output. If wired to SE-type
ground/common wiring, 25 or so driven wires, that means an SE ground
current of 3.75 amps could flow.   That'd be nearly twenty watts of
fault power dissipated in wires or chips.